# What is the proper way of scp'ing between two servers you log in by private key?

Tags: ssh

I have a large amount of data to send from one server to another. I access servers via ssh using a private key.

The problem is that I cannot use that key to scp files from one such server to another - server One doesn't have the private key which server Two expects (only the public part), so Two won't allow access from One.

The only way to send files would be to get them to my computer first (too slow), send private key to one of the servers (probably won't explode in this case, but I really really hate such solutions), or create extra accounts just for that or one of the servers.

Doesn't ssh have some way to let an ssh session forward authorization? That would be really great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have the same public key present in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on both servers, and that you are running some kind of ssh agent locally, then you can use Agent forwarding.

```
localcomputer$ ssh -o ForwardAgent=yes youruser@server.one
```

That way, when you from server.one run your scp session against server.two the authentication will transparently be handled in the background by your local computer . Just note the following warning, taken from ssh_config(5)

> Agent forwarding should be enabled
>   with caution.  Users with the ability
>   to bypass file permissions on the
>   remote host (for the agent's
>   Unix-domain socket) can access the
>   local agent through the forwarded
>   connection.  An attacker cannot obtain
>   key material from the agent, however
>   they can perform operations on the
>   keys that enable them to authenticate
>   using the identities loaded into the
>   agent.

(In short, to a certain degree you will have to trust root@server.one.)

Comment: Note that might not work with scp as it [explicitly disables agent forwarding](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/excerpt/ssh_11/index2.html#59307).

Comment: You can enable agent forwarding with `scp` by using the `-o` flag which allows setting SSH options like in `ssh_config`. For example, `scp -o "ForwardAgent yes" user@host1:/path/to/file user@host2:/path/to/directory`

Answer (score 2):

On a sidenote :

If you're sending large data volumes, you'd better use tar-over-ssh, instead of scp. Is really much faster.

see [howto use tar over ssh](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/)